# How to manipulate GridLayout settings accordingly on JAVA?

Tags: java, grid-layout

I have a setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5,3,3));

5 rows and 5 columns. On the first row I want one big row. You know how in excel, where you would merge cells. So I just want to merge the 5 columns only on the first row. I am putting a JLabel on the first row, and its very annoying that I need to have multiple JLabels for each grid cell and make sure spacing works out well.

Is there a way to do this on GridLayout? Or I am stuck with 5 rows and 5 col strictly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`GridBagLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) can do this. Alternatively, you can use nested layouts: add the first row to the `NORTH` of [`BorderLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) and remaining `GridLayout` to the `CENTER`. See also [*A Visual Guide to Layout Managers*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Addendum: [MiGLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) is also well worth a look in this context. The Web Start demo is particularly appealing, and the manual section on [*Merging and Splitting Cells*](http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf) may be useful.